# Regex for telephone number in ITU format

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate the phone number only in ITU format like +xx xxxxxxxxxx.

Comment: I think before asking u need to show what you have tried as part of question

Answer (score 1):

```
^\+\d{2,3}\s\d{7,15}$
```

Replace the x,y values with the min and max values you want to match.

`\+` since `+` is a special character in regex it needs to be escaped

`\d` is a digit

`\s` is a whitespace character

`^` anchors the regex to the start of the string and `$` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest variant is:

```
\+.. ..........
```

You can also say it so:

```
\+.. .{10}
```

That means that the last symbol (`.`) must be in the string exactly 10 times.

When you need only numbers, you must write `[0-9]` or `\d` instead of dots (`.`).

Comment: dot matches all characters, don't we just want numbers?

Comment: @sachleen: yes, that's right, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Phone numbers can vary from about 6 to about 14 digits including the country code.

The country code can be 1, 2 or 3 digits long.

The number may have an area code from 1 to 6 digits or no area code at all.